# Understanding race_condition_ttl in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, race-condition

I am trying to understand the `race_condition_ttl` directive in Rails when using `Rails.cache.fetch`.

I have a controller action that looks like this:

```
def foo
  @foo = Rails.cache.fetch("foo-testing", expires_in: 30.seconds, race_condition_ttl: 60.seconds) do
      Time.now.to_s
  end
  @foo # this gets used in a view down the line...
end
```

Based on what I'm reading in the Rails docs, this value should expire after 30 seconds, but the stale value is allowed to be served for another 60 seconds. However, I can't figure out how to reproduce conditions that will show me this behavior working. Here is how I'm trying to test it.

```
100.times.map do 
  t = Thread.new { RestClient.get("http://myenvironment/foo") }
  t 
end.map {|t| t.join.value }.uniq
```

I have my Rails app running on a VM behind a standard nginx/unicorn setup. I am trying to spawn 100 threads hitting the site simultaneously to simulate the "dog pile effect". However, when I run my test code, all the threads report the same value back. What I would expect to see is that one thread gets the fresh value, while *at least* one other thread gets served some stale content.

Any pointers are welcome! Thanks so much.

Comment: Try `Time.now.to_f` or `SecureRandom.uuid`. By default `Time.now.to_s` is only accurate to a second, so it's highly probable that even if it did differ you wouldn't notice since it stabilizes so quickly.

Comment: @tadman thanks, let me try that.

Comment: @tadman by using a more granular value I do see some differences. I'll look at the other answer in this thread and see if I can achieve a greater understanding. Thanks!

Comment: Is this thing for real? Seems to me that the problem it is trying to solve is not a race condition and the solution most likely causes a race condition. Do people actually use this? Is there some documentation on how it works and how well it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting `race_condition_ttl` to 60 seconds which means your threads will only start getting the new value after this time expires, even not taking into account the initial 30 seconds.

Your test doesn't look like it would take 1.5 minutes to run which would be required in order for the threads to start getting the new value. From the [Rails Cache docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html):

> Yes, this process is extending the time for a stale value by another few seconds. Because of extended life of the previous cache, other processes will continue to use slightly stale data for a just a bit longer.

The text implies using a small `race_condition_ttl` and it makes sense both for its purpose and your test.

**UPDATE**

> Also note that the life of stale cache is extended only if it expired recently. Otherwise a new value is generated and :race_condition_ttl does not play any role.

Without reading source it is not particularly clear how Rails decides when its server is getting hammered or what exactly `recently` means in the quote above. It seems clear though that the first process (of many) of those waiting to access the cache gets to set the new value while extending life of the previous one. The presence of waiting processes might be the condition Rails looks for. In any case the expected behaviour should be observed after both initial timeout and ttl expire and cache starts serving the updated value. The delay between initial timeout and the time new value starts showing up should be similar to the ttl. Of course the precondition is the server should be hammered around the moment of initial timeout expiration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm reading this to mean that the cache has to be continually read from then, in order for the ttl to kick in? Meaning, if the cache just goes stale after 30 seconds, and then I refresh, there's no reason for the ttl to kick in? But if the server is getting hammered continually, then the ttl will be applied? Sorry if that is unclear.

Comment: I agree with that reading. Please see the update to my answer.